# Match duration using SDL Mixer

Tags: audio, sdl

We have define our basic codes as below. The snippet of the codes play the music chuck when we press the keys accordingly. The issue now is that file1 is shorter and file2 is slightly longer. We need to mix both and play them such a way stretch the duration of file1 to match to file2. How to do via sdl ?

```
Mix_Chunk *file1 = NULL;
Mix_Chunk *file2 = NULL;

 file1 = Mix_LoadWAV( "file1.wav" );
    file2 = Mix_LoadWAV( "file2.wav" );

   while( quit == false )
    {
        //While there's events to handle
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            //If a key was pressed
            if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                //If 1 was pressed
                if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_1 )
                {
                    //Play the scratch effect
                    if( Mix_PlayChannel( -1, file1, 0 ) == -1 )
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                //If 2 was pressed
                else if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_2 )
                {
                    //Play the high hit effect
                    if( Mix_PlayChannel( -1, file2, 0 ) == -1 )
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }             

            }
            //If the user has Xed out the window
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                //Quit the program
                quit = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Any idea how to go about them I am new to it

Comment: You are playing them with channels. They should overlap.

Comment: How to play them on multiple channel and strectch the file1 to match to file2's length

Comment: You can't do that with SDL_mixer.

Comment: Ok what can mixer do then can it play on 2 channel

Comment: @self so what is your advice on playing multiple channels

Comment: I see no reason why you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @Self any snippet of codes on how to use them I saw there is something sdl audio mix I am not sure how to apply them into my codes now

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do some upsampling or downsampling. In your case you might want to upsampling file1 to make it longer. Here's how:

```
// This function add samples from the original audio according to the value of "rate".
// Since the sampling rate remains the same, effectively it will cause the audio to playback slower.
void Play_UpSample (int channel, Mix_Chunk *sample, int loop, int rate)
{
    int m, n;
    Mix_Chunk *newsample = new Mix_Chunk;
    int original_length = sample->alen;
    int length = original_length * rate;    

    newsample->allocated = sample->allocated;
    newsample->abuf = NULL;
    newsample->alen = length;
    newsample->volume = sample->volume;
    Uint8 *data1 = new Uint8[length];
    Uint8 *start = sample->abuf;
    Uint8 *start1 = data1;

    int size = Get_Format();

    if (size == 32) {
        Uint32 sam;

        for (m=1; m<=original_length; m+=4) {
            sam = *((Uint32 *)start);
            for (n=1; n<=rate; n++) {
                *((Uint32 *)start1) = sam;
                start1+=4;
            }
            start+=4;
        }
    }   
    else if (size == 16) {
        Uint16 sam;
        for (m=1; m<=original_length; m+=2) {
            sam = *((Uint16 *)start);
            for (n=1; n<=rate; n++) {
                *((Uint16 *)start1) = sam;
                start1+=2;
            }
            start+=2;
        }

    }   
    else if (size == 8) {
        Uint8 sam;
        for (m=1; m<=original_length; m+=4) {
            sam = *start;
            for (n=1; n<=rate; n++) {
                *start1 = sam;
                start1++;
            }
            start++;
        }


    }   
    newsample->abuf = data1;

    Mix_PlayChannel(channel, newsample, loop);
}
```